# check how many times a function returns a value consecutively

Tags: c#

What is the best way to check how many times a function has returned a value consecutively? For example, running this function in a loop:

```
 static bool F (int i) {
 if (i>1) return true;

 return false;
 }
```

Now

```
 if (function return true consecutively for 10 times ) {Do something}
 else {}
```

I've been doing this by adding the values to a list and then check the content of the list afterwards, but I would like to know what would be the most professional way to do this.

In this way the program takes a very long time to respond.

Comment: If you call the method once, why should it return `true` ten times? How are you calling it, in a loop?

Comment: Yes of course it would be used in a loop

Comment: add the result to a list, and then check if the latest result is same as the previous result

Comment: Careful with your tone Jack, @TimSchmelter is trying to help. Remember, **you** are the one who's asking the question, and **we** are the ones freely giving our **time** to answer it.

Comment: The program freezes for a while since the list will become very large

Comment: @The Solution, I just meant yes, it's running in a loop, I didn't mean anything else, anyway I also edited my question and mentioned the loop as well :)

Comment: put it on a backgroundworker if its freezing, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @The Solution - I think 'the tone' was firmly in the mind of the reader here.  Chill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to count it:

```
int trueCount = 0;
bool wasTrue = false;
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
{
    wasTrue = F(i);
    if (wasTrue)
        trueCount++;
    else
        trueCount = 0;
    if(trueCount == 10)
        ;//Do Something
    else
        ;// Do something else
}
```

Comment: This seems to work a lot faster than my own solution, Thank you very very much for your great help Tim :) I'll accept this answer